# samba server not accesible from ubuntu 14 but possible from android

Tags: 14.04, samba, raspberrypi

**I am using raspbeery pi for smb share,

1. it is accessible from android ES explorer, both public and protected
2. from ubuntu 14 it is able to access only public shared, not able to
   access protected one, keeps asking for usr/pass

**

> my smb.conf, samba Version: 2:3.6.6-6+deb7u3

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security=user
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = no
hide dot files = no
unix extensions = no
lock directory = /var/cache/samba
wins support = no
wins server = 192.168.0.1
encrypt passwords = yes


[SeedBox]
    browsable = yes
    read only = no
    writable = yes
    path = /home/pi
    valid users = pi

[devices]
    browsable = yes
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
    public = yes
    path = /media
    force user = root
```

Comment: Are you using pi as the user and the correct password?

Comment: @dan08 yes, and i am able to access that from android in proper way

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with a bit of reading I managed to come up with a solution. I'm not well versed in this kind of thing so I don't know if this is the best solution but I find that if you change the line under [global] from

security=user

to

security = share

that solved the problem for me. I didn't actually have a "security" setting in my smb.conf so I just had to write the line in the [global] section myself (for anybody else who doesn't have the "security"line).

Comment: are u able to add user authentication ?